# Select2 query search throwing syntax error

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, requirejs, jquery-select2

I'm trying to use the jQuery.select2 plugin. It's part of a Form written in Backbone.js and RequireJS. I'm writing its query /search function, but I'm running into some kind of parsing error I just can't find.

The code for the View is:

```
define([
    'backbone',
    'jquery.select2'
],
function(Backbone, Select2) {

    var notificationSelector = Backbone.View.extend({

        notifications: undefined,

        // events:
        // {
        //  // type letter into box EVENT --> filter populated email list 
        // },

        initialize: function(attrs) {
            this.collection.on('add remove reset', this.render(), this);
            /* select2 Event s.t. call "select2ContactsChanged" ? */

        },

        /*
            <><><><><><><><>
            Getting a syntax / parseerror in the AJAX call below?
            What am I missing?
        */

        render: function() {
            /* DEVELOPMENT SETUP */
                // plucking by "caption" will need to be changed...
            if(this.select2Control == undefined) 
            {
                // Do Search() + query here
                // this.select2Control = this.$el.val(this.collection.pluck('caption').join(' ')).select2({
                this.select2Control = this.$el.select2({
                    width: '200px',
                    placeholder: '@email',
                    tags: [],
                    minimumInputLength: 3,

                    query: function() {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "/notifications/search",
                            dataType: 'json',
                            type: 'GET',
                            //data: {  }, 

                            success: function(data) {
                                /* DEBUG */
                                console.log('AJAX Success!');
                                console.log(data);
                            },

                            error: function(jqXHR, status, error) {
                                    /* DEBUG */
                                console.log('<Failure>');
                                console.log(jqXHR);
                                console.log('-------------------------');
                                console.log(status);
                                console.log('-------------------------');
                                console.log(error);
                            }

                        });
                    }   // END-OF query: function()
                });
            }
            else
            {
                // Go off of what's currently in the Collection and re-render

            }

            // this.$el.select2('data', this.model);
        },

        select2ContactsChanged: function() {
            // when this gets called update this.collection to reflect the this.select2Control's val()

            this.collection.reset(this.select2Control.val().split(' '));
        }

    });

    return notificationSelector;
});
```

the error callback tells me there is a parseerror /syntax error (I'm using the Network section of Chrome's Web Inspector), but I just cannot seem to find it.
Can anyone see what I'm missing or why I might be getting that error?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Any time you use jQuery plugin you need to work with jQuery. Also need to make sure your RequireJS configuration is correct. It is best when plugins are written also as modules.

In your case you also need include dependency from jQuery and no need to map plugin to parameter, because it's jQuery plugin. You just use it. Depenedency array just makes sure it will be loaded.

```
define([
    'backbone',
    'jquery',
    'jquery.select2'
],
function(Backbone, $) {
    // ...
    $('#element').select2();
});
```

I recently [blogged about RequireJS](http://www.devbridge.com/articles/understanding-amd-requirejs) and it explains how you should deal with jQuery plugins.

I suspect the error you are getting is when jQuery is trying to parse JSON that you are sending back. Make sure JSON format is valid. You can validate it using http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: I went ahead and read your blog post, and changed my code to not only define jquery as a module with RequireJS, but to load it (as '$'). Unfortunately, I'm still getting the same unexplained syntax error.

Comment: I suspect error is when parsing returned JSON. Check updated answer.

Comment: By the JSON being sent back over the AJAX request, are you referring to the returned jqXHR object that I log in the error callback?
Or is the JSON you mean separate from that?

Comment: By JSON I mean response body that you are sending from the server.